Why is the actual circuit bandwidth so low for this TIA?
So, I roughly implemented the TIA, I found in this paper  using a transistor array CD-4007's PMOS-es and a single discrete 2N7000 NMOS transistor. I also use a 1 Mega Ohm resistor to measure my output voltage across, instead of the 1 kilo-ohm resistor used in the paper.
Now, according to both the simulations and my calculations, the bandwidth of my modified implementation should be a couple of megahertz, but when I measured it using an oscilloscope FRA, I got around 60 Kilohertz as my cutoff frequency.
The paper says that if anything the bandwidth may increase (compared to the \$f_{cutoff} =\frac{1}{2\pi R_{in}C_{in}}\$) due to the feedback at high frequencies....but my bandwidth is much worse for some reason. Did I setup the oscilloscope FRA wrong? Am I doing the SPICE simulation wrong?
For the oscilloscope FRA, I have given around a 100mV sine wave at a frequency of 1 kilohertz as initial input and according to LTspice, the circuit should draw around 100nA current, so the output of 100mV seems correct. But, its bandwidth being 60kHz instead of megahertz, as predicted by spice seems wrong. In the oscilloscope it started at around 10dB gain, so -3dB with respect to that would be 7 dB gain which is at around 59 kilohertz.


Are you actually simulating and building at a supply voltage of 1 volt?

@Andyaka I have one of those voltage supplies in lab which can go from 0-6V and other two which can go to 0-20V. I am using one of them set to 1.08V, to account for any noise.

Modern CMOS IC processes - that people are writing papers about - have usually very low threshold voltages, well below 1V. If you see multi-GHz CMOS, it'll be definitely targeted for sub-1V thresholds.
Whereas for CD4007 and 4000-series family in general, 1V operation is deep subthreshold. It is very nice that you got any measurable bandwidth at all with a 1MΩ load. That shows that subthreshold operation of a CD4007 array is viable :)
Did you actually look at the datasheets of the CD4007? They have information about device thresholds, some input-output curves, etc. Had you done that, you'd not try running them at 1V :)
Run the thing at 9V and you should get a much more reasonable bandwidth. With a current manufacture CD4007 (coming straight from TI), you'll get best performance somewhere between 9V and 12V, usually.
Remember that the CD4007 devices are nothing like 2N7000. Where did you get the parameters of the NMOS/PMOS models you're using in LTSPice? They are not generally available. You'd have to characterize a CD4007 and extract a basic model yourself, or look around.

I also use a 1 Mega Ohm resistor to measure my output voltage across

That's perhaps not what actually is happening. I assume that you're using a basic 10x scope probe, and not a FET probe like you would need to. Thus, you're shunting the 1MΩ resistor with about 10pF of probe tip capacitance. At 60kHz, that's about 1/3MΩ of reactance that shunts the 1MΩ load! And, based on the circuit construction, you may well have quite a bit more of parasitic capacitance on the output than just 10pF probe tip load.
On a chip, where things are tiny, parasitic capacitances can be in the femtofarad range. As soon as a leadframe is added, i.e. you're working with a packaged leaded chip and not a die or CSP package, there is a couple pF of parasitic pin loading just due to leadframe. A tiny bit more if you add a ground plane under the chip.
To correctly characterize the ultimate performance of the TIA you have designed, you'd need to do inter-transistor connections using bonding wires on a bare die, and use bonding wires to connect to the physically smallest resistors and capacitors you can find. Not a cheap endeavor, but it'd perform quite a bit better than a CD4007 in a package of any sort. The various manufacturers of 4000-series chips did sell them in dice form (cut dies). TI could probably sell dice to you if you asked them for a couple thousand at once...
